# Towers of Hanoi in Java using stacks

Tags: java, stack, towers-of-hanoi

I am writing a program to play the towers of Hanoi game in Java. We are to using stacks to represent the towers. I have an array of 3 stacks two of which I initialize to be empty and the last one to be filled with a user defined amount of discs. I have a Hanoi class file that was given so we can use the Hanoi constructor which takes in an integer and creates a disc of that size. I am having trouble figuring out the code to push the discs onto the stack in my initialize method(their size is a mirror of their position so disc 1 is of size 1 etc.) Any help at all would be appreciated.

**Here is my Hanoi class disc constructor :**

```
public class Hanoi{

private int discSize; //size (radius) of the disc 

public Hanoi(int size){ //creates a disk of the specifed size
    discSize = size;
}
```

**And my initialize method**

```
    public static Stack<Hanoi>[] initialize(int n){

   System.out.println("How many discs in the game?");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int numDisc = sc.nextInt();
   int size = numDisc;

   Stack<Hanoi>[] tower = new Stack[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3;i++){
      tower[i] = new Stack<Hanoi>();
    }
    }


    Hanoi.PrintStacks(tower);
    // System.out.println(hanoi[2].peek());
     return tower;
```

This should initialize all of them to be empty. So should I create a new Hanoi object for each disk based on user input and push them to stack in reverse order?

Comment: First of all, is this homework? If so, should be tagged with "homework". Secondly, you're initializing too many times: the first loop is sufficient. In the second and third, you're just overwriting 2nd, 3rd cell and 3rd cell, respectively.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you happen to study at the University of Windsor? I would recommend having three classes to model the problem: Hanoi, Peg, and Disk. Hanoi will have Pegs A, B, and C. Each Peg will have a stack of Disks.

Comment: Yes this is homework, and thank you I'll fix the initialization. I'm supposed to initialize the first tower as a stack containing discs of size 1-n.

Comment: Nope sorry, but thanks for the advice. We were given a hanoi class that stores information about a single disk in a game.

Answer (score 1):

> So should I create a new hanoi object for each disk based on user input and push them to stack in reverse order?

Yes.

```
for (int i = numDisc; i > 0; --i)
    tower[0].push(new Hanoi(i));
```